# How do I retrieve the values of a link in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In PHP, to retrieve the value of a link in PHP, all I have to do is use `$_GET['value']`

Now in Ruby on Rails, how do I do that? As an example, let say I have this link I want to retrieve its id and use it in a form.

This is the link

```
<%= link_to "Message", new_message_path %># This link will allow the viewer to message the profile owner
```

and this is the message script

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @message %>

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :receiver, value:# The ID should be retrieved from the user id of the previous page %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, size:"20x15" %>
  <%= f.submit "Send message", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you might be talking about query params (such as `receiver_id` on `/new?receiver_id=1234`). You can do this on Rails as well by passing additional parameters to the helper function used to route, such as:

```
<%= link_to "Message", new_message_path(receiver_id: @receiver.id) %>
```

Which would yield something like `/messages/new?receiver_id=1` or whatever.

Then you can use the `params` variable in your controllers in order to access the query params, such as `params[:receiver_id]`, which would yield `1` in this case.

Comment: Won't it conflict with the >create method of rails?  which will create a message/post associated with the login user e.g  @message = current_user.messages.build